# Unable to locate persistence units

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ Idea I created a project with JPA 2.1 and hibernate 4.3.10 final. After I created a datasource (Test connection : Success) I generated persistence mapping from database. Project compiles without error. When I tried to test in JPA Console with a simple Select * query, it returns following exception:

```
[2015-05-21 16:01:27] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
[2015-05-21 16:01:27] java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.

at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.validate(PersistenceXmlParser.java:377)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:310)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:114)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:104)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:86)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:97)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:69)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at com.intellij.jpa.remote.impl.JpaFacadeImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(JpaFacadeImpl.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$2/4400315.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>model.DepartmentEntity</class>
    <class>model.UserEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/svgroup"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this error? I was searching and reading for about 10 hours without success

EDIT

If I try to deploy the app on wildfly without creating entities from database it will deploy the app. However, if I try to deploy the app after the entities are created i get the following error:

```
2015-05-21 18:13:01,697 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 15) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
2015-05-21 18:13:01,704 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 15) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-05-21 18:13:01,711 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 15) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-05-21 18:13:02,183 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service  jboss.deployment.unit."SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar".INSTALL:  org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service  jboss.deployment.unit."SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to  process phase INSTALL of deployment "SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration
at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.process(ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.java:237)
at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.java:130)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration
at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ra.common.ResourceAdapter1516Impl.validate(ResourceAdapter1516Impl.java:352)
at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ra.common.ConnectorAbstractmpl.validate(ConnectorAbstractmpl.java:334)
at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.process(ParsedRaDeploymentProcessor.java:206)
... 7 more

2015-05-21 18:13:02,207 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration"}}
2015-05-21 18:13:02,216 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration"}}
2015-05-21 18:13:02,301 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
2015-05-21 18:13:02,626 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 15) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar#NewPersistenceUnit'
2015-05-21 18:13:02,637 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar (runtime-name: SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar) in 422ms
2015-05-21 18:13:02,640 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."SVGZad4_ejb_exploded.rar".INSTALL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your Jars (JPA / Hibernate) are probably older.
What Jars are you using?

Usually when you download something like Hibernate, they allow you to download sample projects which have the example of such persistence.xml and other files.

**Update**
Maybe the app isn't picking up the expected persistence.xml file?
Try to add some obviously incorrect, invalid text in your persistence.xml file. This way, the exception will printed out with the complete name of the persitence.xml that is being looked at.

Comment: JPA 2.1 and hibernate 4.3.10 final. They are not old. Hibernate is taken with maven.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your persistence.xml

The following line

```
<property name = "hbm2ddl.auto" value = "update" />
```

must probably be changed to

```
<property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value = "update" />
```

Then I suppose you do not have any password in your database

```
<property name = "hibernate.connection.password" value = "?" />
```

Otherwise, I see nothing strange.